# How can I use Extractor Regex in JMeter?

Tags: asp.net, regex, testing, jmeter, performance-testing

How can I extract the parameters of "Location" from the header of the following response?

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: Mon, 11 Jan 2016 13:41:03 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 11 Jan 2016 13:41:03 GMT
Location: hffffer.aspx?GcgvR25kUEPovjjFC8Tv6TErQhGyPEV/aCtmW0wQB76YRC5ShAy/e624URjHnt65zVa8eQCkiOPyB3zIzcKbBhVKSJabVf8z3uqAVKO7tdl8cbHjSQ+/dsTKgxXiuw0B12fhOvPj/pVURdGivisByA==
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 11 Jan 2016 13:41:03 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following Regular Expression Extractor configuration:

- Field to check: `Response Headers`
- Reference Name: anything making sense, i.e. `location`
- Regular Expression: `Location: (.*)`
- Template: `$1$`

Refer extracted value as `${location}` where required.

You may also have to change "Apply to" radio to `Main sample and sub-samples` if there are redirects in your request.

References:

- [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) chapter of JMeter User Manual
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743642)

Comment: Perfect!, Thank You!